# How can I receive error messages from the Python interpreter?

Tags: python

I write Python code in Notepad++, save it to a `.py` file and than run it by double clicking on the file in Windows.

However if there are any syntax errors in the file, the program simply shuts down. I get no error message.

How can I receive error messages regarding problems in the program? Also, what's the best way to code an run Python scripts?

Comment: Open up a command prompt to run the Python. The errors will be displayed on the console and the console will not be automatically closed. (Also, doesn't Notepad++ have support to launch such?)

Comment: @user2864740 In the CMD, is there a way to avoid doing lots of navigating to the folder of the `py` file, or avoid writing the whole path of the file?

Comment: Sure, [create a customized shortcut](http://johnbokma.com/windows/command-prompt-shortcut.html) with an appropriate "Start in". Or, just leave the command prompt open all the time :D For playing around I would also recommend using [Python IDLE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html).

Comment: If you don't want to use the command prompt, you may need a more powerful IDE, like PyCharm or IDLE or emacs. But you really should learn to use the command prompt. People who never learn it just run into problems with working directories, etc., which would be trivial to solve if they understood what it was doing, but it's harder to learn from inside the IDE than from the command line.

Comment: [IPython](http://ipython.org/) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When double-clicking a `.py` file in Windows, the standard program handler will be launched to execute that file. This will be the Python interpreter, which runs in a console window. As soon as the process finished—successful or not—the window closes again, which doesn’t allow you to see the error messages.

In order to keep it around, run your program from within the command line, e.g. by opening `cmd.exe` first and executing the file there. That way, even when the Python process exists, the output will be still visible.